# Rearrange json files

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to rearrange the following JSON which i am having trouble with. I want to convert a format of JSON object into the other for myself. Any help is appreciated. I  Thank you.

From :

```
[
    {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"name":"chris"},
    {"a":11,"b":21,"c":31,"d":41,"name":"chris1"},
    {"a":12,"b":22,"c":32,"d":42,"name":"chris2"}

]
```

To:

```
[
    {
        "name": a,
        "chris":1,
        "chris1":11,
        chris2:12
    },
        {
        "name": b,
        "chris":2,
        "chris1":21,
        chris2:22
    },
        {
        "name": c,
        "chris":3,
        "chris1":31,
        chris2:32
    },    
    {
        "name": d,
        "chris":4,
        "chris1":41,
        chris2:42
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the logic for which object gets each value?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet you could use

```js
let json = [
    {"a":1,"b":"2","c":3,"d":4,"name":"chris"},
    {"a":11,"b":"21","c":31,"d":41,"name":"chris1"},
    {"a":12,"b":"22","c":32,"d":42,"name":"chris2"}

]
let map = {};
for (const obj of json) {
    for( const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (key === "name") continue;
        if (typeof map[key] !== "object") {
            map[key] = {name: key};
        }
        const data = map[key];
        data[obj.name]= value;
    }
}

console.log(map)
```